# Clipboard Bi-Directional Not Working Properly in Debian Guest on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, clipboard

I'm facing a problem with the bidirectional clipboard and drag-and-drop functionality in my VirtualBox Debian guest. Despite configuring bidirectional settings, copying from the host OS to the guest is not working correctly. The guest's clipboard retains only recent text or sometimes copies old content, which is absurd.

Expected Behavior: Seamless bidirectional clipboard and drag-and-drop functionality between host and guest.

Actual Behavior: Clipboard doesn't sync properly, and drag-and-drop is inconsistent.

I use: 
**Kali GNU 2024.1 

VirtualBox 6.1.40**

Other Attempts:

- Tried xsel solution from Ask Ubuntu, but issue persists.
  (https://askubuntu.com/questions/287444/how-to-clean-the-clipboard)
- Downgrading, as suggested by some, is not preferable.
  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799364/virtualbox-guest-additions-clipboard-doesnt-work)
- Couldn't find a solution in:
  [Shared clipboard in Virtualbox with command line only Debian guest](https://superuser.com/questions/451039/shared-clipboard-in-virtualbox-with-command-line-only-debian-guest)

Comment: Did you install VBOX Guest Extensions in Kali ?   Make sure you can map a folder from Kali to the other OS (to make sure there is a connection).

Comment: Straightforward copy / paste works fine here Kali guest, Windows 11 host, VMware, and VMware Tools installed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I followed the steps from "https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-additions/" but the problem persists. Besides, even the "shared folders" feature in VirtualBox is not working.

Comment: You may first need to install and configure Samba to get a working connection.